# Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

i am trying to do a multiple http request using method forkJoin. I need a return all values like a simple request, but i am facing some errors with it.

I am using angular version 8.2.3 and my rxjs version is ~6.3.3

See my service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const PRAGMA = 'pragma';
const NO_CACHE = 'no-cache';
const CACHE_CONTROL = 'Cache-Control';
const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PokemonsService {

    public loadPokemonByQuantity$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public loadPokemonByQuantity(initial: number, final: number):Observable<any>  {
        const callArray = [];
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ CACHE_CONTROL: NO_CACHE, PRAGMA: NO_CACHE });
        for (let index = initial; index <= final; index++) {
            callArray.push(this.http.get<any>(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}`, { headers }));
        }
        return Observable.forkJoin(callArray)
    }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukqqdj)

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and reproduce the issue over there?

Comment: yes, i have another issue in the same project, if you could help me ...  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukqqdj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs';

const PRAGMA = 'pragma';
const NO_CACHE = 'no-cache';
const CACHE_CONTROL = 'Cache-Control';
const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PokemonsService {

    public loadPokemonByQuantity$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public loadPokemonByQuantity(initial: number, final: number):Observable<any>  {
        const callArray = [];
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ CACHE_CONTROL: NO_CACHE, PRAGMA: NO_CACHE });
        for (let index = initial; index <= final; index++) {
            callArray.push(this.http.get<any>(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}`, { headers }));
        }
        return forkJoin(callArray);
    }
}
```

`forkJoin` is a function that returns an `Observable`, it's not a method of the `Observable` class.

Answer (score 1):

with "rxjs": "^6.5.2", use it like this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
forkJoin(...callArray).subscribe(() => {
       // Do something
    });
```

Comment: didn't work :( --> Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: Husam, it's not necesary spread operator, @Jonathan, you MUST import forkJoin from 'rxjs' NOT from ''rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin' tip: all the **Creation Operators** are imported from 'rxjs' (Observable,of,interval,from,fromEvent...), all the rest from 'rxjs/operators' (map,swichMap,merge,...)